# Dart member function equality rules

Tags: function, dart, equality, member

I'm trying to test for equality of a member function of a class. Here is a small sample:

```dart
void main() {
  var foo = new Foo();    

  if (foo.someFunc == foo.someFunc)
    print("foo.someFunc == foo.someFunc");
  else
    print("foo.someFunc != foo.someFunc");
}    

class Foo {
  someFunc() {
  }
}
```

This prints "foo.someFunc != foo.someFunc". The equality operator here should be testing if the functions are the same object in memory (and it seems like they should be.) I also tried using identical(foo.someFunc, foo.someFunc), but got the same result. Why doesn't the equality operator return true in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in [the dart docs](https://dart.dev/language/functions#testing-functions-for-equality).

Basically, you create a different closure each time you use `foo.someFunc`. That's why they are not equals.

Comment: +1 for linking to the same documentation and beating me to the punch. ;)

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense understanding that the reference is a closure.

Comment: In the specific case I'm working on, I really only needed to know that the closures are referencing the same function. So what I ended up doing is using foo.someFunc.toString() to do the comparison instead of == so I don't have to save a reference to the closure for comparison later.

Answer (score 5):

This is explained [here](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-function-equality).  The most important part is this:

> Each time you create a closure, that closure is a new object.

You can store the object in a variable to get around this.  Top-level functions and static methods work as you expect.

```dart
void main() {
  var foo = new Foo();    

  if (foo.someMethod == foo.someMethod)
    print("foo.someMethod == foo.someMethod");
  else
    print("foo.someMethod != foo.someMethod");

  var storedMethodClosure = foo.someMethod;

  if (storedMethodClosure == storedMethodClosure)
    print("storedMethodClosure == storedMethodClosure");
  else
    print("storedMethodClosure != storedMethodClosure");

  if (someFunction == someFunction)
    print("someFunction == someFunction");
  else
    print("someFunction != someFunction");

  if (Foo.staticMethod == Foo.staticMethod)
    print("Foo.staticMethod == Foo.staticMethod");
  else
    print("Foo.staticMethod != Foo.staticMethod");
}

void someFunction() {
}

class Foo {
  someMethod() {
  }

  static staticMethod() {
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
foo.someMethod != foo.someMethod
storedMethodClosure == storedMethodClosure
someFunction == someFunction
Foo.staticMethod == Foo.staticMethod
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is exactly what I needed to know.